# Proper way to stop listening UDP socket with RxExtensions

Tags: c#, udp, system.reactive

I need to listen UDP socket and after 10 seconds or 100 items in buffer some logic should be invoke. Generally it works ok, but i don't know how to proper stop listening socket.

```
var ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
var socket = new UdpClient(ip);

var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var observable =
  Observable
  .FromAsync(socket.ReceiveAsync)
  .DoWhile(() => !cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
  .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 100);

var subscribtion = observable.Subscribe(o =>
{
  //logic
});

//simulate close method from another thread
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12)).Wait();
  cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
  socket.Close();
  subscribtion.Dispose();
});
```

When i simulate closing socket, there exists a situation when exists some data in buffer that can't be processed - is any way to avoid this behavior?

When i send some messages from another process with 500ms delay, it will be works like example below:

1. 20 messages will income
2. Some logic will be invoke - subscriber logic
3. 4 messages will income
4. Simulate close method will be invoke

When "close method" will be invoke i need immediately process all data in buffer and close application without waiting even for buffer timeout. Buffer delay time is defined by user, so i don't want wait for invoke subscriber logic, because it can be a quite long time.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I would like to run some code that demonstrates your issue. Then it can be fixed. I'm going to say though that the solution will be **not** to mix TPL and Rx. Rx is more powerful and that's what you should focus on.

Comment: Thanks for Your interest. Maybe i try re-ask my question and focus more on Rx. In my Example i used Observable with Buffer method. It informs subscribers in every 10 seconds or 100 items in buffer.. But i have a special situation when someone close my app. It can happen in not specified time, so for example if it happen when is third second from last subscribers inform and exists some data in buffer i must hold my app for another 7 seconds to process all data from buffer. Is there any way to say to Observable class (on demand) - stop observer your source and last time inform subscribers.

Comment: What does "stop observer your source and last time inform subscribers" mean?

Comment: On Rx lanugage It be set observable as completed. It will be raise completed buffer metod.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Existing overloads of the buffer method don't support time, count and a gate. But there is an overload which triggers buffer closing when a sequence produces a value. So we will simply create a sequence by merging observables of all the conditions for buffer closing.

Have a look at this demo.

`onTime` will produce a value after the period specified.

`onCount` will produce its first value after `x` items have passed.

`onClose` will immediately produce a value on subscribe - but we won't connect to it until we decide to.

```
            var producer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2));
            var source = producer.Publish().RefCount();

            var onClose = Observable.Return(0L).Publish();
            var onTime = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            var onCount = source.Skip(10);

            var bufferClose = Observable.Merge(onClose, onTime, onCount);

        var subscription =
            source
            .Buffer(() => bufferClose)
            .Subscribe(list => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list)));

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for close");
            Console.ReadLine();

            onClose.Connect(); //signal
            subscription.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Closed");

            Console.ReadLine();
```

This will produce an output based on count or time, until return is pressed, when it immediately closes with what's available in the buffer.

Comment: Tomorrow i will try the solution, but it looks very promising. Thank You.

Comment: @tom how did it turn out?